# Explanation of the Google Gravity trick

Tags: google

I am not much of a JS developer, but I stumbled upon this site called [Google Gravity](http://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google_gravity/) (those who haven't used it, try doing a search there - you'll be amazed), which is a remastered Google homepage. From then on, I've been thinking and wondering about learning more on how the guy implemented it. I tried googling, but could not find a good explanation of the implementation.

All the JS/CSS Gurus, can you point me to a location where I can learn more? I already know the basics of working with jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for the page? It should tell you just about everything you need to know.

Comment: It has been some time since I've seen a less usable interface than that (Gravity).

Comment: @James yes, had a look. But as I said, I was looking for a top level explanation of the code - as the code is 2k+ lines, and some part is very obfuscated :)

Comment: @Rook - I don't think usability was ever the developer's concern :)

Comment: @yati - Oh! Well, in that case - job well done :)

Comment: It might be interesting to note (if you don't know already) that the author of the demo in question is the primary author of three.js, and a SO user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What it does, besides using mathematical formulas (for which, you have to be good at math), is using the native technologies of web coming under HTML5 and CSS3.

I recommend that you read these items:

1. [CSS Transitions](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understanding-css3-transitions/)
2. [CSS Animation](http://thoughtresults.com/css-animations)
3. [Timing Control for Script-Based Animations](http://thoughtresults.com/timing-control-for-script-based-animations)

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the javascript source code?

I just took a very quick look (and it's far from my cup of tea) but it looks like the page is broken up into 2d boxes and a simulation of those boxes free falling under gravity is ran.  Then the mouse events are handled to allow those boxes to be interactively manipulated.

Comment: Yes, that seems like the way to go, but I could have used a top level explanation first, as this is not my forte, either. After doing a search, even the results appear in movable 2D boxes, and the previous debris is still there!